# Rotate drawn rectangle on canvas when key pressed

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've had a look through related questions on SO but can't seem to find what i'm looking for. I'm really, really new to canvas so to get some practice I started writing a very small platform game engine. So far, i've got a little square to jump and move around the screen, however my next step is to give this little square a weapon. There are tons of tutorials on how to make projectiles but nothing on how to make a melee weapon (like a sword). So this is what I want to achieve.

Here is Mr. Cube

[image]

Mr. Cube needs a weapon. I can add this to my update function:

```
// Draw player
ctx.fillStyle = player.fill
ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

// Draw weapon
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(player.x + 20, player.y - 20, 8, 30);
```

This gives me my desired look

[image]

So i've drawn the weapon onto the canvas like so, using the x,y values as the the player x,y values so it's always attached to Mr Cube. Of course, these will be swapped out for proper graphics at some point, but this will essentially serve as an invisible hit box. My question is this:

How do I create a function that rotates this drawn rectangle (Like swinging a sword). It's really confusing me. An image of what i want to achieve is here:

[image]

This is my JavaScript thus far

```
// Platform game prototyping engine

// Globals

player_created = 0;
environment = 0;
debug_on = false;

// Request frames

(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

/**
  * New Game
  * @desc Creates canvas and context then sets the height and width
  * @param [string] canvas - Canvas ID in your HTML
  * @param [integer] width - Canvas width
  * @param [integer] height - Canvas height
  * @param [string] bg - Canvas background color
*/

function new_game(canvas,width,height){
    game = document.getElementById(canvas);
    ctx = game.getContext("2d");
    game.width = width;
    game.height = height;

}

/**
  * New Player
  * @desc Creates a single player on the canvas
  * @param [integer] x - Player x position on canvas
  * @param [integer] y - Player y position on canvas
  * @param [integer] width - Player width
  * @param [integer] height - Player height
  * @param [integer] speed - Player movement speed
  * @param [integer] jumpVel - Player jump amount
  * @param [string] fill - Player fill color
*/

function new_player(x,y,width,height,speed,jumpVel,fill){
    player = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fill: fill,
        speed:speed,
        velX:0,
        velY:0,
        jumpVel:jumpVel,
        jumping: false
    }
    keys = [];

    ctx.fillStyle = player.fill;
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    ctx.fill();
    player_created = 1;
}

/**
  * New Environment
  * @desc Creates the game environment
  * @param [integer] friction - Sets the environment platfrom friction
  * @param [integer] gravity - Sets the environemnt gravity
*/

function new_environment(friction,gravity){
    environment = {
        friction: friction,
        gravity: gravity
    }
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    });
    document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    });
}

function debug(){
    ctx.font = "11px Verdana";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText('Velocity X: ' + player.velX,20,30);
    ctx.fillText('Velocity Y: ' + player.velY,20,50);
    ctx.fill();
}

function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,game.width,game.height);
    if(player_created == 1){

        // Draw player
        ctx.fillStyle = player.fill
        ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

        // Draw weapon
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(player.x + 20, player.y - 20, 8, 30);

        if(environment == 0){
            console.log('%c No environment has been created! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
        }
        if (keys[38]) {
            // up arrow or space
            if(!player.jumping){
                player.jumping = true;
                player.velY = -player.jumpVel;
            }
        }
        if (keys[39]) {
            player.velX =+ player.speed;         
        }     
        if (keys[37]) {                 
            player.velX =- player.speed;
        }

        player.y += player.velY;
        player.x += player.velX;
        player.velY += environment.gravity;
        player.velX *= environment.friction;

        if (player.x >= game.width-player.width) {
            player.x = game.width-player.width;
        } else if (player.x <= 0) {         
            player.x = 0;     
        }

        if(player.y >= game.height - player.height){
            player.y = game.height - player.height;
            player.jumping = false;
        }
    }
    if(debug_on == true){
        debug()
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    update();
});

new_game('game',600,600)
new_player(250,250,20,20,4,20,'red')
new_environment(.9,1)
```

A live version can be found here

http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/d6308fc86305d70c875c30f9452aa4d6?editors=1010

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ctx.rotate()` function before drawing a rectangle, then revert the rotation.

Add the following code after `if(player_created == 1){` row 96 in your example to get started:

```
ctx.save(); // save current rotation and coordinates
ctx.translate(player.x + player.width, player.y); // set canvas draw start to new rect coordinates
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4); // 45 degrees for example
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(0, -25, 10, 30); // 10 by 30 rect, shifted 25 y up
ctx.restore(); // restore to old rotation and coordinates
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
```

Comment: this is great. So if i hook this up to a keypress can i change the rotate value over time. In other words it will animate to that rotation rather than snap to it?

Comment: Yeah, for animation you will have to store the current rotation in a variable and increase/decrease the variable based on the time the button was pressed.

You already use requestAnimationFrame, so you can find the time passed since starting the animation in the first parameter of the update function. Change `function update(){` to `function update(thisLoop){` and console.log(thisLoop) to check the timestamp. To avoid undefined variable thisLoop on the first run, change the animation start (row 138 in your example) to: `requestAnimationFrame(update);`

Comment: Good answer upvote. Just a word on performance: `save & restore` will save and restore all of the context properties (not just the translate & rotate transformations). It's more efficient to undo only the translate,rotate. Do that by calling the original transformations in reverse order with negative values: `ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/4); ctx.translate(-player.x-player.width, -player.y)`. Or alternatively reset all the transformations to "untransformed" with `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` ;-)